# Providing await to a code which throws an Exception is giving error in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner to flutter development. I want to learn the logic behind this :

Below provided code is a basic code that I wrote to understand the error which I got in unit testing my `AuthProvider`

Providing `await` keyword to the `provider.createUser()` redirects to `await` statements in `remote_listener.dart` and `invoker.dart` when debugging. When unit testing with this logic, fails the test.

My Question:  Why should we avoid `await` in a code where we expect to throw an exception when unit testing

```
void main() async {

  final provider = MockAuthProvider();
  final result = await provider.createUser(
    email: 'email@email.com',
    password: 'testPassword',
  );

}


class MockAuthProvider {

Future<AuthUser> createUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {

    if (!isInitialized) throw NotInitializedException();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    const user = AuthUser(email: 'email@email.com', isEmailVerified: false);
    return user;
}
```

The actual Unit testing code is provided below. The test fails when an `await` is given to the `badEmailUser` and `badPassword` as shown below. If we remove the `await`, the test passes.

The thing I wanna know is why providing `await` fails the test? What is the logic behind the code?

```
      group('Mock Authentication', () {
        final provider = MockAuthProvider();

        test('Create user should delegate to login', () async {
        
        final badEmailUser = await provider.createUser(
            email: 'bad@email.com',
            password: 'test',
        );
        expect(badEmailUser,
            throwsA(const TypeMatcher<UserNotFoundAuthException>()));

        final badPassword = await provider.createUser(
            email: 'email@email.com',
            password: 'badPassword',
        );
        expect(badPassword,
            throwsA(const TypeMatcher<WrongPasswordAuthException>()));

        final user = await provider.createUser(
            email: 'email@email.com',
            password: 'testPassword',
        );
        expect(provider.currentUser, user);
        expect(user.isEmailVerified, false);
        });
   });
}


class MockAuthProvider {

    Future<AuthUser> createUser({
        required String email,
        required String password,
    }) async {

        if (!isInitialized) throw NotInitializedException();
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
        const user = AuthUser(email: 'email@email.com', isEmailVerified: false);
        return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is mostly correct. There are a couple things you can do to make it more robust and resolve your issue, though.

Here's one option:

```dart
void main() async {

  final provider = MockAuthProvider();
  AuthUser? result;

  try {
   result = await provider.createUser(
      email: 'email@email.com',
      password: 'testPassword',
    );
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle the error
  }

  if (result == null) // Handle the null case

}


class MockAuthProvider {

Future<AuthUser> createUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {

    if (!isInitialized) throw NotInitializedException();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
    const user = AuthUser(email: 'email@email.com', isEmailVerified: false);
    return user;
}
```

Another option is to handle the error in your `createUser` method:

```dart
void main() async {

  final provider = MockAuthProvider();
  final result = await provider.createUser(
    email: 'email@email.com',
    password: 'testPassword',
  );
  
  if (result == null) // Handle the null case
}


class MockAuthProvider {

Future<AuthUser?> createUser({
    required String email,
    required String password,
  }) async {
    AuthUser? user;
    try {
      if (!isInitialized) throw NotInitializedException();
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
      user = AuthUser(email: 'email@email.com', isEmailVerified: false);
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle the error here
    }

    return user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time bro :)  Actually the error was shown when unit testing. I wrote the above code to make it easy to understand the error. As I'm a beginner, I would like to know why the await gives an error. I'll edit the question to add the unit testing code also.

Comment: Without knowing more, I'd assume a couple of things: 1) `if (!isInitialized) throw NotInitializedException();` is throwing the exception because there's no `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`. 2) the `await` itself isn't throwing the exception, rather it's the method which throws the exception. Typically, I'd use code generation in my tests to mock the API responses, but I'm not sure your code is set up for that. It would require dependency injection and mockito.